# How to concatenate unsized parameters

Tags: verilog, synthesis

My verilog module is instantiated in a VHDL top entity. I want to pass integer design-time configurations to the verilog module. These are the initial configurations that should appear at reset.

```
module abcmod
#(
  parameter  [23:0] VT_PARAM1           = 1280,
  parameter  [7:0]  VT_PARAM2           = 53,
 ..
)
( .. );

reg [31 : 0] params; 

always @( posedge Clk )
  begin
    if ( Resetn == 1'b0 )
      params <= {VT_PARAM1,VT_PARAM2}; //Assign default 32-bits
    ..
```

The above examples compiles with Xilinx ISE 14.4, but does not function. VHDL parameters are not passed to verilog parameters with [L-1:0]. Only parameters with unsized `parameter par_name = DEF_VALUE,` format works.

So I have to pass integer parameter values, unsized, then verilog should expand them to 24 and 8 before concatenate them. How could I possibly do this?

Comment: Can you upgrade to ISE 14.7 (the last ISE release from fall 2013)? They added a lot of bugfixes and 'featues' since 14.4.

Comment: Unfortunately, the team is too big to upgrade all those workstations. Many things are stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can SHIFT and OR them

```
params <= (VT_PARAM1 << 8) | VT_PARAM2; //Assign default 32-bits
```